# Proof of If $K$ is a finite extension of $F$, then $K$ is algebraic and finitely generated over $F$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

The following lemma appears in Fields and Galois theory book by Patrick Morandi

> If $K$ is a finite extension of $F$, then $K$ is algebraic and finitely generated over $F$

and in its proof uses the fact that if $\text{dim}_{F}(K)=n$ then for every $a\in{K}$ the set $\{1,a,\dots,a^n\}$ is linearity dependent.

And it isn't clear to me why that's true. I thought the reason was that the set $\{1,a,\dots,a^n\}$ have n+1, but for $a=1$ we have $\{1,a,\dots,a^n\}$=$\{1\}$. So I guess that the set always has not n elements. Any hint to see that?

Comment: For $a = 1$ this is not true.

Comment: What that textbook claims is that the set $\{1,a,\ldots,a^n\}$ is linearly dependent.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos yeah, but I think uses that the set have n+1 elements because is mentioned "since $[K:F]=n$". Or why must be linearly dependent?

Comment: If it was linearly independent $\dim_F K \geq n+1$.

Comment: That's true if the set $\{1,a,\dots,a^n\}$ indeed have n+1 elements, but in the case of a=1, we have that $\text{dim}_{F}(K) \geq{1} $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The claim is NOT that $\{1, a, \dots, a^n\}$ consists of $n+1$ elements but that the set is linearly dependent (over the base field $F$).
If $\{1, a, \dots, a^n\}$ has less than $n+1$ elements this is clear. Say we have $a^i=a^j$ for $i,j \le n$ and $i \ne j$. Then the non-trivial linear combination
$$1 \cdot a^i + (-1) \cdot a^j =0$$
shows that the set is linearly dependent.
If it has exactly $n+1$ elements - then the fact that dim$_F(K)=n$ gives that any set of $n+1$ or more elements is linearly dependent over $F$ meaning there is a non-trivial linear combination
$$ c_0 + c_1a + c_2a^2 + \dots + c_na^n =0$$

In both cases we have a polynomial such that $f(a) = 0$ (first case: $f(x) = x^i-x^j$, second case $f(x) = c_0 + c_1x + \dots + c_nx^n$) - hence $a$ is algebraic over $F$ which was to be shown.

Comment: Yes, I know that's not the claim, I just forgot to re-edit the question . Thank you so much for answering.